# Joomla module display

Tags: templates, module, joomla, position

I want to create a page in Joomla that displays only one specified module on a page **and nothing more**.  I was trying to insert module in an article but it's not working because plugins are also adding content to an article, and I don't want to turn them off. MAybe I should create a template with a new position, and override default template on that specific page but maybe there's a better solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is coded to either expect an article or the output of a component on every page. I don't completely understand why you can't just insert a blank article with the `{loadposition module_position}` code unless your plugins are *automatically* generating content for articles. I'm used to plugins that only work when their plugin code is added to an article. Anyway, assuming that your plugins are *automatically* adding content to your Joomla articles, then the simple solution might be to add a new component like [Zoo](http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/) and use the "Pages" app to create a blank/no-title item that contains the `{loadposition xx}` code, then link your menu item to that Zoo item.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as I said before: plugins add other stuff to an article, and I can't deactivate them globally. Installing new components is a little bit overdo, I think. I solved the problem by  overriding my default template with a template that has no <jdoc:include type="component" /> tag and only one position for modules <jdoc:include type="modules" name="onlyoneposition" />. To this position I assign the module I want to be displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the parameters of the article? Those should allow you to turn off the title, author, icons, date, and other elements that may be appearing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I haven't found anything to turn off the contenet of an article. So I'm still sticking to overriding my default template with a template that has no <jdoc:include type="component" /> tag and only one position for modules <jdoc:include type="modules" name="onlyoneposition" />. To this position I assign the module I want to be displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be possible by this condition in index.php 
countModules('condition')) { ?>
     do something

     do something else

you can put what you want in this module and according to this condtion you have to only insert module name in countModules('your module Name') followed by bhe code in the braces. and for rest of pages you can put your code in the else part.